# Getting "Class not found" in bitbucket pipeline issue

Tags: magento2, compile

In my build from my pipeline, I am receiving this error:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Swagger\Client\Api\ProductsApi' not fou  
  nd in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Model/Api/ProductsApi.php:16
```

when it comes to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. But when I run locally the `setup:di:compile` command , I don't get any errors! It happens only during the pipeline deployment.

Does anyone have a clue about this ?

Comment: can you post the pipeline script here?

Comment: @ManafPM I'm using a deployer from Hipex: https://github.com/HipexBV/DeployConfiguration. But not sure if it has to with that

Comment: If you are developping locally on a Mac I would suggest you to check your case where you use Swagger\Client\Api\ProductsApi in the file app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Model/Api/ProductsApi.php. It hapenned to me pretty often having issues on my deployment to a linux server because Mac's are case insensitive.